NoHostAvailableException while connecting kafka and cassandra
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Couldn't connect to Cassandra.
    at io.lenses.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.source.CassandraSourceTask.start(CassandraSourceTask.scala:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.initializeAndStart(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:280)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:202)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:259)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.run(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:77)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:236)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042] Cannot connect), localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:270)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:109)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.negotiateProtocolVersionAndConnect(Cluster.java:1813)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1726)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:214)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:387)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:338)
    at io.lenses.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.CassandraConnection$.getSession(CassandraConnection.scala:93)
    at io.lenses.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.CassandraConnection$.apply(CassandraConnection.scala:39)
    at io.lenses.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.source.CassandraSourceTask.$anonfun$start$2(CassandraSourceTask.scala:82)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:210)
    at io.lenses.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.source.CassandraSourceTask.start(CassandraSourceTask.scala:82)
    ... 10 more

I wanted to connect kafka and cassandra to import data from cassandra tables into a kafka topic and yet somehow this exception is coming.
{
  "connector.class": "io.lenses.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.source.CassandraSourceConnector",
  "connect.cassandra.key.space": "my_keyspace",
  "connect.cassandra.contact.points": "localhost",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "connect.cassandra.port": "9042",
  "connect.cassandra.kcql": "INSERT INTO cas_topic1 SELECT * FROM my_table",
  "connect.cassandra.password": "cassandra_password",
  "connect.cassandra.poll.interval.ms": "1000",
  "connect.cassandra.username": "cassandra_user"
}

this is my kafka-connect configuration for cassandra source.

Everything is running on the same machine? Not using Docker or VMs?

The stack trace you posted indicates that the Kafka connector is not able to connect to the Cassandra cluster on localhost which suggests to me that your Kafka Connect instance is not running on the same machine.
If Kafka Connect and Cassandra are not hosted on the same OSI, you need to configure the Cassandra node so that it is listening for CQL client connections on an IP address that is publicly accessible.
You will need to set rpc_address in cassandra.yaml to the node's IP that is reachable from the Kafka Connect instance. Cheers!
